# Spring WebUtils error fro every request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

we decided to update spring framework from 4.1.6 to 4.2.5 recently. After that the following error appeared:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils.isSameOrigin(WebUtils.java:816) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.cors.DefaultCorsProcessor.processRequest(DefaultCorsProcessor.java:71) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping$CorsInterceptor.preHandle(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:503) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExecutionChain.applyPreHandle(HandlerExecutionChain.java:134) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:954) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:870) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) [servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [servlet-api.jar:?]
```

This happens with every AJAX request on the REST API from our site. I did a little research and found the following in WebUtils:

```
public static boolean isSameOrigin(HttpRequest request) {
    String origin = request.getHeaders().getOrigin();
    if (origin == null) {
        return true;
    }
    UriComponents actualUrl = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpRequest(request).build();
    UriComponents originUrl = UriComponentsBuilder.fromOriginHeader(origin).build();
    return (actualUrl.getHost().equals(originUrl.getHost()) && getPort(actualUrl) == getPort(originUrl));
}
```

Which means the only place where that error may occurs is `actualUrl.getHost().equals`. When I opened the build() method I've found:

```
public UriComponents build(boolean encoded) {
        if (this.ssp != null) {
            return new OpaqueUriComponents(this.scheme, this.ssp, this.fragment);
```

The getHost() method is defined in OpaqueUriComponents as follows, which definitely results in null in all cases and raises a NullPointerException.

```
@Override
public String getHost() {
    return null;
}
```

Do you think it's a spring bug or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Michal

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered this problem when using nginx proxy.
`actualUrl.getHost().equals()` throws NullPointException, because tomcat server cannot get host from http header.

Have you use nginx proxy?

when nginx forwarded request to tomcat server, some infos in http header may lost, so I add these in nginx.conf and it works:

`proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

proxy_set_header Origin $http_origin;`

Answer (score 0):

I'd check out Example 8 on [this site](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.springframework.web.util.UriUtils). In summary, it looks like different mecahnics are being used to get the host:

`UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(responseEntity.getHeaders().getLocation()).build();`

where `getLocation()` is used where you're using `getOrigin()`

Comment: Hi @Blake, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately the all code samples, i've posted, are separated from Spring sources and not even used directly by my. I think it's used by Spring Security when processing Http request.